# density of a set of arithmetic means

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is there a sequence $x_n$ such that the set of its values $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but the set of arithmetic means $\{\frac{x_1+\dots+x_n}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ isn't dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

A very natural question I asked myself and can't answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose an enumeration $\{x_n\}_{n\ge1}$ of the positive rationals $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$. Construct a new sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\ge0}$ with

1. $a_0=0$,
2. $a_{2n-1}=x_n$,
3. $a_{2n}=-x_n$.

This gives an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$ which is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, however it is easy to see that the arithmetic mean will always be $\ge0$.

Comment: very clever, thanks